# Can a IPython parallel controller both have local and remote ipengines?

Tags: python, ipython-parallel

The IPython [parallel docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/parallel/parallel_intro.html) mention:

```
c = Client(profile='myprofile')
```

or

```
c = Client('/path/to/my/ipcontroller-client.json')
```

for local ipengines (IIUC) and

```
c = Client('/path/to/my/ipcontroller-client.json', sshserver='me@myhub.example.com')
```

if my ipengines are on another server.

But what do I need to do to have the IPython parallel controller, let's say, manage 8 ipengines from the local node and 8 ipengines from a remote node, connected via SSH?

Or is that not possible without going full scale HDFS,Hadoop etc.?

My target is to have one client (or controller?) interface that I can send a bunch of calculations in a load-balanced fashion, where I don't care where what is run and when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sshserver arg to Client is only for when the Controller is not directly accessible from the Client (e.g. Client on laptop, Controller behind a firewall on a remote network). The Client doesn't ever need to know or care where Engines are. Further, ssh tunnels are only required when the machines are not accessible to each other. I'll assume that you don't actually need ssh tunneling for simplicity.

The simplest case:

- `host1` is where you want to run the Controller, Client, and 5 engines
- `host2` is another compute machine on the same LAN, where you want to start 8 engines

### No config

1. start the controller, listening on all interfaces (so engines elsewhere on the LAN can connect)

   ```
   [host1] ipcontroller --ip=*
   ```
2. (skip if shared filesystem) send connection files to host2

   ```
   [host1] rsync -av $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/security/ host2:.ipython/profile_default/security/
   ```
3. start engine on host1

   ```
   [host1] ipengine
   # or start multiple engines at once:
   [host1] ipcluster engines -n 5
   ```
4. start engines on host2

   ```
   [host2] ipengine
   # or start multiple engines at once:
   [host2] ipcluster engines -n 8
   ```
5. open a Client on host1:

   ```
   [host1] ipython
   In[1]: from IPython import parallel
   In[2]: rc = parallel.Client()
   ```

You should now have access to engines on both machines.

### With config

You can express all of this with configuration, as well. To initialize the config files:

```
[host1] ipython profile create --parallel
```

Tell ipcontroller to listen on all interfaces in `ipcontroller_config.py`:

```
c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
```

Tell ipcluster to launch engines with ssh, on both host1 and host2 in `ipcluster_config.py`:

```
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SSH'
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {
    'host1': 5,
    'host2': 8,
}
```

Start everything with `ipcluster`:

```
[host1] ipcluster start
```

The SSH launcher will take care of copying connection files around to the remote engines.

If you do need ssh tunneling, you can specify

```
c.IPControllerApp.ssh_server = u'host1'
```

in `ipcontroller_config.py`. IPython ought to be able to tell if engines or clients are running on `host1`, and skip tunneling if it's unnecessary. If it can't figure that out, you can either manually specify where the ssh server should be used and leave it out of config, or put it in config and manually specify that no ssh server should be used, whichever is more convenient for you.

Comment: I thought doc from @minrk at `https://minrk.github.io/scipy-tutorial-2011/parallel_process.html`, specifically the numbered list of steps in the `General Considerations` section, was also pretty informative (really just a more manual version of the `rsync` given in the current answer).